# How to avoid images from assets "popping" onto the screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When displaying images *from assets* using the `Image` widget, they tend to "pop" onto the screen a few milliseconds after other widgets like `Text`.

Is there a way to have the image already on the screen, since it's from assets? So it doesn't pop (or fade) into view?

Here's a simple example that causes this:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('This text will be visible a few ms before the image renders',),
      Image.asset('images/lake.jpg',),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: I've got these behavior just in debug. Do you have this issue in release mode as well?

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue with the release build @siega

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to call [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) in the `build` function of a widget that's an ancestor to the widget that needs to show the image.

I'm calling it in the widget I provide to `runApp` in `main.dart`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(AssetImage('images/lake.jpg'), context);
    return MaterialApp(...);
}
```

Comment: Didnt help me out... Still have the poping effect

Comment: any other solutions you have found?